# Composable monadic std::function using std::optional

Tags: c++, c++17

I've implemented a simple `Maybe` type around `std::function` that implements function composition where any function in the composition can fail (causing the entire composition to fail) - in essence, a Maybe monad where `operator<<` implements `bind`.

For example,

```
  // one binary function that cannot fail.
  std::function<int(float, float)> h  =
    [](const float a, const float b) -> int {
                                             return a * b;
                                        };


  // a unary function that CAN fail.
  std::function<std::optional<int>(int)> g =
    [](const int c) -> std::optional<int> {
                                           if (c < 0) return std::nullopt;
                                           else return c;
                                          };
                                                                                    
  // another unary function that CAN fail.
  std::function<std::optional<bool>(int)> f =
    [](const int d) -> std::optional<bool> {
                                            if (d < 10) return true;
                                            else return std::nullopt;
                                           };

  // compose f, g, and h
  auto G = Maybe(f) << Maybe(g) << Maybe(h);

  // evaluate the composition - this maps (float, float) -> optional<bool>
  auto result = G(1.0, 7.0);

  // and check if the computation was successful
  if (result) std::cout << "Result: " << *result << "\n";
  else std::cout << "Computation failed!\n";
```

Here is my current implementation:

```
#include <functional>
#include <optional>
#include <iostream>

template <typename TReturn, typename... TArgs>
struct Maybe {

  /**
   * The (lifted) function that we evaluate.
   */
  std::function<std::optional<TReturn>(const std::optional<TArgs>...)> eval_;

  /**
   * Lift a non-failable function into the Maybe monad.
   */
  auto lift(std::function<TReturn(const TArgs...)> const& f) {

    // construct a lambda that implements the Maybe monad.
    return [f](const std::optional<TArgs> ... args) -> std::optional<TReturn> {
        if ((args && ...)) return f(*(args)...);
        else return {};
    };
  }

  /**
   * Lift a (failable) function returning an optional into the Maybe monad.
   */
  auto lift(std::function<std::optional<TReturn>(const TArgs...)> const& f) {

    // this overload is currently necessary so that I can extract the TReturn
    // value type so that `eval_` doesn't pick up another layer of std::optional
    // i.e. std::optional<std::optional<int(float, float)>>.

    // construct a lambda that implements the Maybe monad.
    return [f](const std::optional<TArgs> ... args) -> std::optional<TReturn> {
        if ((args && ...)) return f(*(args)...);
        else return {};
    };

  }

  /**
   * Construct a Maybe from a std::function returning an optional.
   */
  Maybe(std::function<TReturn(TArgs...)> const f) : eval_(lift(f)) {}

  /**
   * Construct a Maybe from a std::function returning an optional.
   */
  Maybe(std::function<std::optional<TReturn>(TArgs...)> const f) : eval_(lift(f)) {}

  /**
   * Apply the Maybe to the given arguments.
   */
  auto operator()(std::optional<TArgs> const... args) const {
    return this->eval_(args...);
  }

  /**
   * Compose the callable in `this` with the callable in `other`.
   *
   * @param other    Another monadic filter instance.
   */
  template <typename TOReturn, typename... TOArgs>
  auto operator<<(Maybe<TOReturn, TOArgs...> const& other) const -> Maybe<TReturn, TOArgs...> {

    // get references to the underlying lifted functions
    // capturing the Maybe instances into the lambda results in a seg-fault
    auto f = this->eval_;
    auto g = other.eval_;

    // construct the coposition lambda
    std::function<std::optional<TReturn>(TOArgs...)> fg =
      [=](TOArgs... args) -> std::optional<TReturn> { return f(g(args...)); };

    return fg;
  }


}; // END: class Maybe
```

This is targeting C++17 only. Any and all feedback appreciated!

There's currently some duplication in the constructors and the `lift` method so that I wrap functions that already return `std::optional` without being wrapped in a second layer of optional i.e. `std::optional<std::optional<...>>` which makes the composition impossible (I'm sure there is some template trickery that could make this work with just a single method and constructor).

Answer (score 2):

You have the exact same comment (`Construct a Maybe from a std::function returning an optional`) on two different constructors. I don't think the comment was necessary anyway. Both constructors should be `explicit`, to prevent implicit conversions.

Using `return {}` instead of `return std::nullopt` strikes me as needless obfuscation. (In the same way, I wouldn't use `return {}` when I meant `return nullptr`.)

---

Your use of const-qualified function *parameter* variables is an antipattern (see my blog post ["`const` is a contract"](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2019/01/03/const-is-a-contract/)). In this particular case, it prevents you from moving-out-of the parameters, which is exactly what you should want to do here:

```
static auto lift(std::function<TReturn(TArgs...)> f) {
    return [f = std::move(f)](std::optional<TArgs>... args) -> std::optional<TReturn> {
        if ((args.has_value() && ...)) {
            return f(std::move(*args)...);
        } else {
            return std::nullopt;
        }
    };
}
```

You're actually very lucky that `std::function<TReturn(const TArgs...)>` and `std::function<TReturn(TArgs...)>` happen to be the same type! You use the two spellings inconsistently throughout this code. Stick to the simpler shorter one.

---

It would probably make sense to try to provide an overload of `operator<<` taking rvalues on left and/or right, to avoid some copying.

It's surprising that `operator<<` returns a `std::function<...>` instead of a `Maybe<...>`. I don't actually see what that buys you.

---

As ALX23z said, it's unfortunate that you build everything around `std::function` instead of around arbitrary callables. For example, I couldn't write

```
auto f = [](int x) -> std::optional<int> { return (x < 10) ? x + 1 : std::nullopt; };
auto g = [](int y) { return y * 2; };
auto G = Maybe(f) << Maybe(g);
assert(G(5) == 12);
assert(G(12) == std::nullopt);
```

As I write that, I realize that it's also pretty confusing to me that you picked `<<` to mean "compose with." [Wikipedia tells me](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition) that the notation I'm familiar with, `f ∘ g`, is also ambiguous — does it mean "f(g(x))" or "g(f(x))"? Well, I might pick something like

```
auto g_of_f_of_x = Maybe(f).then(g);
auto f_of_g_of_x = Maybe(f).of(g);
```

so as to be completely unambiguous.

---

Using `std::function` allowed you to cheat around one of the [perennial impossibilities of C++](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2018/06/12/perennial-impossibilities/#detect-the-first-argument-type-of-a-function): detecting a callable's "argument types." This means you can't use your `Maybe` with generic lambdas or templates like `std::plus<>`. If I were writing it, I'd ditch that cheat and try to make it work for generic lambdas from the very beginning.

You can see my worked solution [here on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/fnWP4d) — notice the left-hand pane using `std::function` for your `f,g,h` variables, and the right-hand pane using `auto` to make them actually lambda types, thus eliminating all the `std::function` overhead. The meat of my solution is

```
template<class Callable>
struct Maybe {
    Callable f_;
    explicit Maybe(Callable f) : f_(std::move(f)) {}

    template<class... Args>
    auto operator()(Args&&... args) const
        -> decltype(optional_of(f_(value_of(static_cast<Args&&>(args))...)))
    {
        if ((has_value(args) && ...)) {
            return f_(value_of(static_cast<Args&&>(args))...);
        } else {
            return std::nullopt;
        }
    }
};

template<class T, class U>
auto operator<<(const Maybe<T>& a, const Maybe<U>& b) {
    // "a << b" means "a(b(x))"
    return Maybe([a, b](auto&&... args) {
        return a(b(static_cast<decltype(args)>(args)...));
    });
}
```

`value_of`, `optional_of`, `has_value` are just overload sets with special overloads for `std::optional`.

Making this code safe against ADL is left as an exercise for the reader — but I think basically you can just slap a `namespace detail` around the helper bits and you'll be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

First issue with this design is that it is going to be slow and non-optimizable. `std::function` has a couple of features that hide type and implementation and neither is easy to optimize nor cheap. If you make complex functions that run in milliseconds than it is of no problem at all but otherwise consider a different more efficient approach.

Second issue, is that if a function returns `std::optional` and composed with function that accepts `std::optional` and does something non-trivial when `std::nullopt` is supplied then the `Maybe` composition will change output. I don't think that this is what uses desires.

Also, the naming isn't good `Maybe`... come up with something more meaningful and intuitive.

---

To deal with the first issue, first look for an inspiration to `std::bind` as one can see in the [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) it doesn't return a `std::function` but an unspecified type. Why?

One possible implementation is that it returns a lambda that calls the function with the given arguments. That's it. And in this way it is a see-through method which is easily convertible to `std::function` and other function/method wrappers. (To implement placeholders feature its complexity raises beyond that of just generating a trivial lambda function that forwards arguments.)

Imagine what `std::bind` would generate if supplementing each argument was done via an operator and converting to a `std::function` each time - instead of the variadic template approach? That would be a disaster I assure you.

For instance, `boost::format` uses operators to fill arguments while `fmt::format` relies on variadic template approach... and as a result `fmt::format` is considerably faster both in performance and in compilation time. (Can't blame `boost::format` as it was implemented and designed way before C++11)

So it would be much better if you wrote a template function that generates a callable from a sequence of callable:

```
template<typename... Collables>
auto compose_callables(Callables...){...}
```

This will also allow you to address the second issue about how to properly implement the "optional" feature: suppose you compose `f` with `g` to make `f(g)`. And input type of `f` is `Arg` and function `g` returns output `std::optional<Arg>` then abort the execution whenever the optional has no value. However, forward the argument as is when the function `f` accepts the same type that `g` returns even if it is an `std::optional` of something.

To implement this properly you'll need to stretch some muscles with template meta programming and SFINEA. This is quite challenging for most C++ programmers. Wish you luck if you attempt to.